# Array to string conversion error when trying to POST multidimensional array

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I am getting the following error notice:

Array to string conversion in /path/to/wp-includes/class-wp.php on line 281

I have a form that is for frontend submissions to create custom post type posts. This form has "add more" group fields generated with jquery:

```
<fieldset id="education">
        <legend>Education</legend>
        <ul id="edu-group" class="form-fields">
            <li class="layout layout--flush add-more-field group-field">
                <div class="layout__item one-quarter">
                    <label for="institution_0_name" data-pattern-text="Institution +=1">Institution </label>
                    <input type="text" name="institution[0][name]" id="institution_0_name" data-pattern-name="institution[++][name]" data-pattern-id="institution_++_name">
                </div><div class="layout__item one-tenth">
                    <label for="year_0_name" data-pattern-text="Year +=1">Year </label>
                    <select name="year[0][name]" id="year_0_name" data-pattern-name="year[++][name]" data-pattern-id="year_++_name">
                        <?php yearDropDownDesc(1960, date("Y")); ?>
                    </select>
                </div><div class="layout__item one-quarter">
                    <label for="course_0_name" data-pattern-text="Course +=1">Course </label>
                    <input type="text" name="course[0][name]" id="course_0_name" data-pattern-name="course[++][name]" data-pattern-id="course_++_name" >
                </div><div class="layout__item one-quarter">
                    <label for="grade_0_name" data-pattern-text="Grade +=1">Grade </label>
                    <input type="text" name="grade[0][name]" id="grade_0_name" data-pattern-name="grade[++][name]" data-pattern-id="grade_++_name">
                </div><div class="layout__item one-tenth">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn--small btn--remove">-</button>
                </div>

            </li>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn--icon btn--small btn--addmore">Add +</button>
        </ul>

    </fieldset>
```

Only when I add these fields the error notice happens.I believe this is because of name attributes being institution[0][name] etc although I am not sure why looking at line 281 of the class-wp.php

I have tried setting query_var to false for the custom post type but that didn't work. Can anyone shed light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select name="year[0][name]" id="year_0_name" ...
```

The variable "year" is a variable already used by the WordPress query system.

Take a look at the top of the file where you see "$public_query_vars" to see the ones WordPress is already using and expecting to be something different than what you're sending to it.

Use different variable names than those. I would recommend prefixing all your variable names with something unique to your specific case, so as to avoid these sort of conflicts.

Comment: Oh man, I was reading the codex about query_vars and I just figured it out. Came to close thread. Thanks so much. D'oh!